# how to render data in vertical Tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tabs

I need to  render data using React vertical tabs, I have given code which I have tried and also the data coming from API. **I am not getting how to loop inside `<TabPanel>`**.
link for codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-darkness-qob1n?file=/src/tab.js

```js
      <Tabs
                defaultTab="vertical-tab-one"
                vertical
                className="vertical-tabs"
              >
                <TabList>
                  {subProducts.map((subProduct, index) => (
                    <Tab>{subProduct.subProductName}</Tab>
                  ))}
                </TabList>
                {subProducts.map((subProduct, index) => (
                  <TabPanel className="tab-pane fade mt-4 show  ">
                    {subProduct.bookingDetails.map((attr, i) => (
                      <>
                        <table id="customers">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>{attr.name}</td>
                              <td>{attr.value}</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </>
                    ))}
                  </TabPanel>
                ))}
              </Tabs>
```

API output:

```js
subProducts: [
        {
          bookingDetails: [
            {
              name: "Birthday Decoration",
              value: "YES"
            },
            {
              name: "Photographer",
              value: "NO"
            }
          ],
          subProductName: "Celebration"
        },
        {
          bookingDetails: [
            {
              name: "Decoration",
              value: "YES"
            },
            {
              name: "Video",
              value: "NO"
            }
          ],
          subProductName: "FamilY"
        }
      ]
```

Comment: can you make an image from what you expect as the final result?

Comment: TabList is working fine but tabPanel giving error.

Comment: make your code sandbox, pls

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-darkness-qob1n?file=/src/tab.js

Comment: please check this issue..

Comment: @kp97338 Your sandbox is currently pretty empty. Can you add some code to it that actually reproduces your problem?

Comment: @Bas van der Linden i have updated code please check it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sandbox you try to map over `bookingDetails` for each object in the `subProducts` array, but in the second object of `subProducts` you have a `Details` property, but not a `bookingDetails` property so `bookingDetails` will be undefined.

So you probably want to change `Details` to `bookingDetails`:

```
subProducts: [
  {
    bookingDetails: [
      {
        name: "Birthday Decoration",
        value: "YES",
      },
      {
        name: "Photographer",
        value: "NO",
      },
    ],
    subProductName: "Celebration",
  },
  {
    bookingDetails: [
      {
        name: "Decoration",
        value: "YES",
      },
      {
        name: "Video",
        value: "NO",
      },
    ],
    subProductName: "FamilY",
  },
];
```

If the API returns `Details` instead of `bookingDetails` as in your original question do it the other way around. Change it so it maps over `Details` instead:

So `subProduct.Details.map` instead of `subProduct.bookingDetails.map`.

---

The data not being displayed correctly on click is because each `Tab` component need to have a `tabFor` prop value that corresponds with a  `TabPanel`'s `tabId` prop value. Otherwise `react-web-tabs` doesn't know what content to show when.

For this example I've used the map's index and called `toString` on it before passing it to the props as the id needs to be a string. But a more natural `id` would be to have `id` fields in your data and use those.

[Example Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-breeze-mt8o1?file=/src/tab.js:86-149)

Comment: thank you ,yes correct approach but data is not changing in tab panel.